# I messed up my partitions

Tags: dual-boot, mount, partitioning

I mounted linux onto my windows partition. I tried to make a windows bootable so many times and live boot it but the screen flashes blue when i try and boot it. Im completly lost and I really want windows back so i can install ubuntu on the correct partition. The dual boot screen works fine but when i press on the windows button, it goes into the windows screen that says its diagnosing the system. Ive tried getting the iso and restoring from that with a usb and it doesnt read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you boot from a USB, make sure you are booting into it from the bios. If that doesn't work, then your motherboard is the issue.

From there you can try fixing/reinstalling windows. it also allows you to edit partitions if you want. After you reinstall though, you will probably lose access to Ubuntu, as windows over writes the access, Since you have it all in one hard drive.